# Reference managed package class in target org lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, managed-package

We have a managed package installed in target org/sandbox. We are developing custom code (Lightning aura component) for client. I need to reference the class in managed package as controller for this lightning component. `<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride" access="global" controller="referenceManagePckClass">`
. I tried Global controller with global method. But the code logic is visible in target org. how do I reference managed package class for lightning components.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate the namespace:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride" controller="your_pkg_namespace.referenceManagePckClass">
```

You don't need to make it global unless you want it to be usable outside of your own org.

Comment: Thank you Alba. I need to make a http request from this same lightning component. there is a password saved in protected custom setting of the managed package. can this controller handle the callouts in the target org by accessing the custom setting?

Comment: When a custom setting is contained in a managed package, and the visibility is set to Protected, access is allowed only through the Apex code that is part of that managed package.